# How to avoid data fragmentation in an "INSERT once, UPDATE once" table?

Tags: sql, postgresql, mvcc

I have large number of tables that are "INSERT once", and then read-only after that. ie: After the initial `INSERT` of a record, there are never any `UPDATE` or `DELETE` statements. Due to this, the data fragmentation on disk for the tables is minimal.

I'm now considering adding an `needs_action` boolean field to every table. This field will only ever get updated once, and it will be done on a slow/periodic basis. As a result of MVCC, when `VACUUM` comes along (with an even slower schedule) after the `UPDATE`, the table becomes quite fragmented as it clears out the originally inserted tuples, and they get subsequently backfilled by new insertions.

In short: The addition of this single "always updated once" field changes the table from being being minimally fragmented by design, to being highly fragmented by design.

**Is there some method of effectively achieving this single `needs_action` record flagging that can avoid the resulting table fragmentation?**

.

.

.

.

---

<***And now for some background/supplemental info...***>

---

***Some options considered so far...***

At the risk of making this question massive (and therefore overlooked?), below are some options that have been considered so far:

1. Just add the column to each table, do the `UPDATE` and don't worry about resulting fragmentation until it actually proves to be an issue.

   - I'm conscious of premature optimization here, but with some of the tables getting large (>1M, and even > 1B) I'd rather get the design right up front.
2. Make an independent tracking table (for every table) only containing A) the PK from the master table, and B) the `needs_action` flag. Create a record in the tracking table with an `AFTER INSERT` trigger in the master table

   - This will preserve "INSERT only" minimal fragmentation levels on the master table... at the expense of adding (significant?) up-front write overhead
   - putting the tracking tables in a separate schema would also neatly separate the functionality from the core tables
3. Forcing the `needs_action` field to be a HOT update to avoid tuple replication

   - Needing an index on `WHERE needs_action = TRUE` seems to rule out this option, but maybe there's another way to find them quickly?
4. Using table fillfactor (at 50?) to leave space for the inevitable `UPDATE`

   - eg: set fillfactor to 50 to leave room for the `UPDATE`, and therefore keep it in the same page
   - But... with only one `UPDATE` it seems like this will leave the table packing fraction eternally at 50% and take twice the storage space? I don't 100% understand this option yet... still learning.
5. Find a special/magical field/bit in the master table records that can be twiddled without MVCC impact.

   - This does not seem to exist in postgres. Even if it did, it would need to be indexed (or have some other quick finding mechanism akin to a `WHERE needs_action = TRUE` partial index)
   - Being able to optionally suppress MVCC operation on specific columns seems like it would be nice here (although surely fraught with peril)
6. Storing `needs_action` *outside* of postgres (eg: as a `<table_name>:needs_copying` list of PKs in redis) to evade fragmentation due to mvcc.

   - I have concerns about keeping this atomic, though. Maybe using `redis_fdw` (or some other fdw?) in an `AFTER INSERT` trigger can keep it atomic? I need to learn more about fdw capabilities... seems like all fdw's I can find are all read-only, though.
7. Run a fancy view with background defrag/compacting, as described in [this fantastic article](https://www.targeted.org/articles/databases/fragmentation.html)

   - Seems like a bit much to do for all tables.
8. Simply track ids/PKs that need copying in a postgres table

   - just stash ids that need action as records to a fast inert table (eg: no PK), and `DELETE` the records when action is completed
   - similar to `RPUSH`ing to an offline redis list (but *definitely* ACID)
   - This seems like the best option at the moment.

Are there other options to consider?

---

***More on the specific use case driving this...***

I'm interested in the general case how to avoid this fragmentation, but here's a bit more on the current use case:

1. Read performance is much more important than write performance on all tables (but avoiding crazy slow writes is clearly desirable)
2. Some tables will reach millions of rows. A few may hit billions of rows.
3. `SELECT` queries will be across wide table ranges (not just recent data) and can range from single result records to 100k+
4. Table design can be done from scratch... no need to worry about existing data
5. PostgreSQL 9.6

Comment: [Follow the zeroth rule of optimization: don't do it until you need to](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize), and then only when you can measure it. Are you currently having disk fragmentation issues? Are they causing performance problems? Have you done profiling to determine its disk fragmentation? Do you know it's caused by the inserts and updates? Can you handle this by defragmenting or vacuuming?

Comment: #4: More information on fillfactor (read "Page Splits"): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/specify-fill-factor-for-an-index. Fillfactors tell SQL Server how much space on a page to remain "blank" with expectations that the data will be filled in later through update/insert. Being as your table is mostly for reading purposes, I'd have a fillfactor of 90-100%.

In terms of query speed, this will come from your table design and indexes that you build on the table. 

I'd recommend focusing on good table design and indexes.

Comment: @Schwern: Taking some time to consider good design practices up front is not ALWAYS the evil "premature optimization", contrary to popular opinion. :) I do know that at least one of the tables will reach > 1B rows, and am spending some time now considering the best design options. Then they will be tested and profiled at scale.

Answer (score 2):

I would just lower the fillfactor below the default value of 100.

Depending on the size of the row, use a value like 80 or 90, so that a few new rows will still fit into the block. After the update, the old row can be “pruned” and defragmented by the next transaction so that the space can be reused.

A value of 50 seems way too low. True, this would leave room for all rows in a block being updated at the same time, but that is not your use case, right?

Comment: 100% of rows will definitely get updated, and all at the same time. A background process lurks and waits for new rows and, when it kicks into action it addresses *all* rows needing action, then flipping the `needs_action` flag to `FALSE`

Comment: Just adding a note that Oracle PCTFREE defaults to 10% which I believe is analogous to a Postgres fillfactor of 90. Test and measure the impact it of course but the suggestion above of using fillfactor of 80 or 90 as starting point sounds bang on.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use inherited tables. This approach does not directly support PK for tables, but it might be resolved by triggers.

```
CREATE TABLE data_parent (a int8, updated bool); 
CREATE TABLE data_inserted (CHECK (NOT updated)) INHERITS (data_parent);
CREATE TABLE data_updated (CHECK (updated)) INHERITS (data_parent);



CREATE FUNCTION d_insert () RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
    NEW.updated = false;
    INSERT INTO data_inserted VALUES (NEW.*);

    RETURN NULL;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql SECURITY DEFINER;

CREATE TRIGGER d_insert BEFORE INSERT ON data_parent FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE d_insert();


CREATE FUNCTION d_update () RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
    NEW.updated = true;
    INSERT INTO data_updated VALUES (NEW.*);
    DELETE FROM data_inserted WHERE (data_inserted.*) IN (OLD);

    RETURN NULL;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql SECURITY DEFINER;

CREATE TRIGGER d_update BEFORE INSERT ON data_inserted FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE d_update();


-- GRANT on d_insert to regular user
-- REVOKE insert / update to regular user on data_inserted/updated


INSERT INTO data_parent (a) VALUES (1);


SELECT * FROM ONLY data_parent;
SELECT * FROM ONLY data_inserted;
SELECT * FROM ONLY data_updated;



INSERT 0 0
 a | updated 
---+---------
(0 rows)

 a | updated 
---+---------
 1 | f
(1 row)

 a | updated 
---+---------
(0 rows)


UPDATE data_parent SET updated = true;

SELECT * FROM ONLY data_parent;
SELECT * FROM ONLY data_inserted;
SELECT * FROM ONLY data_updated;


UPDATE 0
 a | updated 
---+---------
(0 rows)

 a | updated 
---+---------
(0 rows)

 a | updated 
---+---------
 1 | t
(1 row)
```

Comment: This is a really interesting approach, since both output tables will only get written to once. It reminds me a bit of the method used in the article I linked, if only because accessing all data would require a `UNION` view of the `data_inserted` and `data_updated` tables. I'll have to test what such a split view (with 2x the indexes and extra planning impact, for example) does to read performance.

Comment: Also, although write performance is less important than read performance in this case, I'm curious what diverting the *entire* initial `INSERT` does to performance. Since the first table never actually has anything written to it, it seems like it could be negligible? I'll also have to test this.

Comment: You do not need to use UNION to access datas in both table - just try to SELECT without ONLY from data_parent. When tables is not big than penalty for DELETE/INSERT is big. But if your table  is big it gives advantages. + You can create not only one table for updated  record - it might b data_yearmonth and you can move data to it after some period

Comment: Thanks, Roman. `INHERITS` is new to me and I missed that behaviour.